# mongos slow after shardcollection added

Tags: performance, mongodb, sharding

So we have a big collection with about a 100 million records. We need to shard and I'm doing some testing. I found out that performance decreased when running a query on a collection that is sharded, even with only 1 shard.

I started a mongos and added the mongod to the shardcluster (so basically only 1 server yet). When I do a .explain() query with about 230000 return values, the response time is about 800ms, which is the same when I query directly on the mongod server.
I enable sharding for this specific collection, still the same response times (800ms).
Now I enable sharing for the cluster and add a shard key, the response times increased to 1400ms for the exact same query over mongos. When I query directly on mongod the response times are still 800ms. Also all other queries to collections that are not sharded show equal response times on mongos and mongod, but once a collection is sharded, the response times significantly increased (almost doubled).

What happened and why are the response times got significantly worse? This is helding us back to shard. We need 2 shards to get equal performance with one single big server, which should not be the essence of sharding...

Comment: Not sure whether following is the case with you or not. 
For the first query, mongos will always go to the config server for the shard information for that query(shard-key), later it caches those information.
Can you try running the same query twice in both of your scenarios and try to compare the 'millis' again.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have ran the same query multiple times and got consistent results. The bigger the query (more results) the bigger the difference (always about 40-50%). Tested it with very quick queries, but the response times difference is relatively the same.

Also tried non sharded collections, but those response times are identical on mongos or mongod.

I profiled CPU usage of mongos and mongod and could see that mongod was using up to twice as more cpu when the query comes from the mongos, then when the query is directly ran on the mongod. Index is used in both situations